# Partitions in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

We have few tables in db with partitions created on  range of  `create_date` . In postgressql it is forcing me to include `create_date` in primary key. because of this when i write any upsert query using `ON CONFLICT`, i am able to insert duplicate rows because create_date changes with timestamp.

```
CREATE TABLE t_address (
        zip_code varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        number varchar(80) NOT NULL,
        name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        category varchar(20),
        create_date timestamp,
        last_modified timestamp    
) PARTITION BY RANGE (create_date) ;
```

Primary key was on `zip_code` and `name` (Oracle). But Postgres is forcing me to add `create_date` also into primary key.

when i write the upsert using conflict

```
Insert into t_address (...)
on conflict(zip_code,name,create_date)
update (...)
```

this is allowing duplicates since create_date is changes every second.

Can you guys please suggest any solution. I have these 2 solutions in mind.

1. take out partitions and delete from main table (through config value which is in hours).
2. In case if I have to keep partitions to make deletes easy, what keys and constraints I should define?. Do i need to write trigger to generate partitions?.
3. query table for record whenever any insert comes, update if exists or insert. I mean check if the  data exist and then do insert/update.  (not using `ON CONFLICT`). But if i implement this I am not using primary key at all    and querying db each time when an insert request comes.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Create date is very unlikely to be useful as part of a primary key. Your supposed to be able to find rows via their PK value - how is a querier supposed to know exactly when a row was created to find it?

Comment: @Schwern It's range partitioning not list partitioning

Comment: As written, t_address has no primary key so there's no problem with partitioning by create_date. Can you show us the actual schema for t_address (`\d t_address` in psql) and your partitions? Edit them into your answer.

Comment: You can still have an unique index on only `zip_code` and `name`, and also use that for `on conflict`.

Comment: I meant to say, edit them into your *question*. My mistake.

Comment: In another table--oracle PK and unique indeses are on zipcode. But postgres forcing me to add create_date(parttiton key) in both PK and Unique index. In stored proc code    on conflict if I am using any of this, I am inserting duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key with create_date is not effective on practice.
Because of index size postgres sometimes decides to use full scan instead of PK on some partitions. But you can specify PK on each partition instead.

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS  t_address_xyz 
PARTITION OF t_address (primary key (zip_code,name)) 
FOR VALUES ...
```

in order to use upsert you need to know what partition will be used in query so your query will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO t_address_xyz 
VALUES ... on conflict (zip_code,name) 
DO UPDATE ...
```

It can be difficult to maintain but if you keep partition strategy clean it can be acceptable.